# Get list of words from text file

Tags: python, list, file

In my code on line I have no idea why it is wrong I've tried a gazillion different ways but they don't work. I want it to print out:

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

romeo.txt is the text document name
this is whats inside:

> "But soft what light through yonder window breaks It is the east and
>   Juliet is the sun Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon Who is
>   already sick and pale with grief "

Also the output is in alphabetic order.

```
fname = "romeo.txt"#raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    lst.append(line)
    words = lst.split(line)
#   line = line.sort()
print lst
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fname = "romeo.txt"
fh = open(fname)
lst = []
for line in fh:
    words = lst.split(line) # this comes first
    lst.extend(words) # add all the words to the current list

lst = sorted(lst) # sorts lexicographically   
print lst
```

Comments in code. Basically, split up your line and accumulate it in your list. Sorting should be done at the end, once.

---

A (slightly) more pythonic solution:

```
import re
lst = sorted(re.split('[\s]+', open("romeo.txt").read(), flags=re.M))
```

Regex will split your text into a list of words based on the regexp (delimiters as whitespaces). Everything else is basically multiple lines condensed into 1.